# Como funciona o método prod do numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Eu sempre utilizei o método `np.prod` como um operador de produtório. Assim, se quero saber o fatorial de 5, por exemplo, simplesmente faço:

```py
import numpy as np

np.prod([5,4,3,2,1])
```

120

Ocorre que estava trabalhando hoje e notei uma inconsistência nesse procedimento. Estava contando o número de combinações possíveis de 12 pessoas fazerem aniversário em dias diferentes. Seguindo minha interpretação do `np.prod` fiz:

```py
np.prod([365,364,363,362,361,360,359,358,357,356,355,354])
```

4433906698518895616

Esse valor está errado. O correto é obtido na expressão:

```py
365*364*363*362*361*360*359*358*357*356*355*354
```

4657431227433109900901013888000

Por que o `np.prod` retornou o resultado errado? Como funciona esse método?

Comment: Não é por causa do overflow? A [documentação](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html) diz: "*Arithmetic is modular when using integer types, and no error is raised on overflow*" - ver também https://stackoverflow.com/q/39089618

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A biblioteca Numpy é, em sua maioria, escrita em C com wrapper para Python. Desta forma, Numpy vai seguir as limitações de tipo de C, e portanto o problema que você tem é derivado da própria limitação de inteiros da linguagem C.

Em C, int64 possui um alcance de `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` até `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` e o seu resultado esperado possui o valor de `4,657,431,227,433,109,900,901,013,888,000` o que claramente int64 não suporta.

Você pode seguir a recomendação na [resposta do Marcus Nunes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/491619/220173) e utilizar Floats para aumentar o alcance que o produtório pode alcançar, mas este também eventualmente vai chegar a um limite definido pela linguagem C.

Para contornar este problema, em Python 3 inteiros possuem tamanhos ilimitados. Desta forma, você pode definir uma função que calcula o produtório e assim terá o resultado esperado:

```
def produtorio(minha_lista):
    p = 1
    for elemento in minha_lista:
        p *= elemento
    return p

minha_lista = [365,364,363,362,361,360,359,358,357,356,355,354]
print(produtorio(minha_lista))
```

O código acima retornará o resultado esperado: `4657431227433109900901013888000`

Answer (score 2):

O array `[365,364,363,362,361,360,359,358,357,356,355,354]` é entendido como um array de números inteiros. Assim, ocorre um overflow no python se algum valor inteiro ultrapassa o valor máximo que é possível representar:

```
np.prod([365,364,363,362,361,360,359,358])
-3541793775766646656
```

Por exemplo, na multiplicação acima, o resultado foi tão grande que números negativos passaram a ser produzidos. Se os resultados continuarem a crescer, eles vão se tornar cíclicos: vão crescer tanto que outro overflow vai acontecer e eles ficarão negativos novamente, repetindo esse processo.

Uma forma de evitar isso é declarar a array como float. Basta adicionar um ponto ao final de cada número que ele deixará de ser inteiro.

```
np.prod([365.,364.,363.,362.,361.,360.,359.,358.,357.,356.,355.,354.])
4.65743122743311e+30
```

Ou seja, a limitação não está no método `prod` em si, mas sim na maneira como o python lida com inteiros.